confluence forge custom ui get editable body
I am making a custom ui forge confluence app.
I used MacroConfig for the content and want to make the body editable.
Like when on edit mode the user can change it and does not need to open the Macro Config.
I saw an old app that used the $body element.
I researched the manifest.yml configuration on how to make the body editable, but no luck.
